# TypeScript and JQ Plugin (Angular4)

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-plugins

I try to use JQ Plugin inside a component in Angular 4 project.
Here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from "../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "../../../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";

@Component({
 selector: 'app-table',
 templateUrl: './table.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('select').material_select();
    });
}

}
```

"material_select" is a function from the plugin.
But in my console I see next:
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4zo1.png)

Guess I don't understand how to import jq plugin here.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps.

1. `npm install --save @types/jquery`
2. `declare var $: JQueryStatic;` in your code before the `class` and then you can use jquery as before.
3. extend jquery interface.

   ```
   interface JQueryEx extend JQuery {
     material_select(): any;
   }
   ```
4. add `($('select') as JQueryEx).material_select()` to `ngAfterViewInit()` function and remove the code from `ngOnInit()`.